# Ellipsis in dijit/Form/Select options

Tags: forms, select, dojo, ellipsis

I have a dijit/form/Select component which I make declaratively. I want to add text-overflow:ellipsis style for each option. I've tried giving id to the component and then I've set:

```
    #myselectorid_dropdown td,
    #myselectorid span{
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        max-width:50em;
    }
```

Firstly, this solution doesn't fully work, because at first dropdown open, the ellipsis style is not applied (at next opens it is). Secondly, I consider it a "dirty" solution (there should be a cleaner way to do it, right?).

So the question is: how to add text-overflow:ellipsis to each select's options?

EDIT: I gave *autoWidth:false* attribute to the Select component, so it fixed the first issue (improper width at first open). I'm still looking for cleaner solution than td/span styling though.

Answer (score 3):

Try using .dijitSelectLabel instead of span

```css
#myselectorid .dijitSelectLabel {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width:50em
}
```